# PSL$_2(\mathbb{R}$) is path connected?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology

first of all I'm sorry if my question is really easy or maybe dumb, but my knowledge in topology is a problem and I'm not find that information or prove in any place. I've proved that the space SL$_2(\mathbb{R})$ is path connected using exponencial matricial, but I'm not sure if that property remains under the equivalence relation that defines PSL$_2(\mathbb{R})$. I appreciate if you can help me, anyway, thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: Consider the quotient map $\pi:SL_2(\mathbb{R}) \to PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$. This map is continuous (pretty much because we give $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ the quotient topology) and the continuous image of a path-connected space is path-connected. So yes, it is path connected.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm in doubt about somethings, can you write explicity this quotient map ? And you are considering the quotient topology for the PSL$_2(\mathbb{R})$ space ?

Comment: Well, the quotient map is exactly that, it sends $A \in SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ to its representative $[A] \in PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and yes we give $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ the quotient topology.

Comment: Hm, Ok, can you give me some help in other question ? I'm in doubt if PSL$_2(\mathbb{R}) \setminus \{ I \}$ is path connected too, it's seems clear, isn't ?

Comment: I haven't thought about it, but you can't use the same logic here. This is not a (topological or group) quotient, but rather a set difference. You are *removing* (the image of) $I$ so you might change path connectivity of the space.

Comment: Thought some more and I think it's still path connected. $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a 3-manifold so $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a 3-manifold, and for a 3-manifold, removing $1$ (or even finitely many) point won't change path connectivity.

Comment: Sorry, but I've never study Manifolds, that result is valid only for 3 dimensional manifold ? And do you now if the prove is difficult ?